# Click button with hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Need get this fixed as I've been trying for a month. Can you look at my website for the button that doesn't work?

http://www.insightenergy.eu/about-us.php

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include screenshots and a complete (but short) code sample that shows your problem, as opposed to simply linking to an external site, and also include tags indicating the language(s) you're using.

Comment: When you see at the console log, there are some errors on your Javascript code... It seems you're trying to use some deprecated properties with a new version of jQuery, and this is causing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach an event to your buttons, and when I debug I get nothing on click.

Looking at your web I think you maybe need something like that:
Your HTML structure is similar to this one:

HTML

```
<ul class="blog-post-full-list">
    <li >
        <div >0</div>
        <div class="expandible">Content</div>
    </li>
    <li >
        <div >1</div>
        <div class="expandible">Content</div>
    </li>
    <li >
        <div >2</div>
        <div class="expandible">Content</div>
    </li>
    <li >
        <div >3</div>
        <div class="expandible">Content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So in your code you can use the JQuery function toggle:

JS

```
$(".blog-post-full-list>li").on('click',function(){
    /*
     *The object this is the li you've clicked on
     *The jQuery function toggle swiches the display ON OFF
     *The number 300 means the duration of the animation. If you don't 
     *    want to animate it just remove the parametter 
     */
    $(this).find(".expandible").toggle(300);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vzkUL/2/

You can add it into a JS file or inline in your code as follows:

```
<script>

//JQuery onReady
$(function(){

  $(".blog-post-full-list>li").on('click',function(){
    //The object this is the li you've clicked on
    //The jQuery function toggle swiches the display ON OFF
    //The number 300 means the duration of the animation. If you don't want to animate it just remove the parametter
    $(this).find(".expandible").toggle(300);
  })

});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, it is near there but it would not show and hide. As Function fail

Comment: Ok, but what do you expect? If you don't want to show and hide, what do you want to do from the function? 
Also you should add into the question the code HTML that you want to fix and the JS code that you have tried to implement and it is not working.

Comment: Still dont work. the code i use this<ul class="blog-post-full-list">
    <li >
        <div class="f1 clearfix expander"><a class="btn-small wide"<span>$row[title]<div class="right"</div></span></a><br>
        <div class="expandible">$row[content]</div>

Comment: Let's do something.
Try to add that code inline inside a script tag as I updated in the answer

Comment: Also, that code that you have posted here you should add it inside you question, on the top. 
You can edit it and complete the information. 
In fact, the negative punctuation that you have is because of the lack of information

Answer (score 0):

try the following code to expand or minimize the container.

```
$('.expander').click(function(){

     if(condition){
        $('.expander').next().show();
     }
     else{
        $('.expander').next().hide();
     }});
```